# Opencv How to apply a filter within a mask

Tags: python, opencv, mask, sobel

I want to apply a sobel filter to an image, but I want to apply it only inside a mask I have defined. I know I can do `cv2.bitwise_and` and obtain only the image inside the mask, but that would also gives me an edge between the mask and the inner image that sobel would detect as a border.

So how can I apply a filter (in my case `cv2.Sobel(dni,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)`) to an that part of an image that's only inside the mask?

Thanks!

Comment: what about applying the mask to the _result_ of Sobel?

Comment: Good point! I didn't think of that

Comment: I just tried and it works perfectly fine. Thanks!